# How to display badly decoded Unicode characters in Excel cells in their original language?

Tags: excel, vba

For cells with 'gibberish' on an Excel file, I need to present them (e.g. in another cell or at least, for now, in a message box), in the language they originate from.

I found a hint for a solution at https://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html, but couldn't pull through a working code.

What I did:

1. merge the 'variables' block into one (there are two there),
2. paste all the functions in below the declared variables (as one converts undecoded Unicode strings to bytes, and the other to properly encoded Unicode strings),
3. and assuming I want to display cell A1, I slightly modified the last part of the code that should do the trick, to:

```vb
Public Sub Test_Utf8String()
    Dim abData() As Byte
    Dim b() As Byte
    Dim a As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveSheet
        abData = StrConv(.Cells(1, 1).Value, vbFromUnicode)
        a = ""

        For i = 0 To UBound(abData)
            If i = UBound(abData) Then
                a = a & Hex(abData(i))
            Else:
                a = a & Hex(abData(i)) & " "
            End If
        Next

        b = Utf8BytesFromString(a)
        s = Utf8BytesToString(b)
        MsgBox (s)
    End With
End Sub
```

It throws errors I cannot cope with.

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting?

Comment: This is the error with the current code. Changes might bring up other errors:

"Argument not optional", and it highlights "WideCharToMultiByte" in:

' Get length in bytes *including* terminating null
    nBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0&, ByVal StrPtr(strInput), -1, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&)

under the function with heading:

"Public Function Utf8BytesFromString(strInput As String) As Byte()"

The functions can be seen in the URL provided in my post.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, add this info to your post by editting it

Comment: Right. Thank you, I will do so right now.

Comment: Couldn't. Will try again later...

Comment: Actually it won't matter that much because every change to the code brings up new errors. I would be grateful if someone could check it or try it briefly and provide a solution, a working code...

Comment: Could you upload some sample so I can test my code?

Comment: Thank you so much David! Being new to StackOverflow and just passing by for this very important question, I'm still not sure how to upload files, but simply type this into cell A1 and try if that displays well:

ÐžÐ±Ñ‰Ð¸Ð½ÑÐºÐ° Ð±Ð¾Ð»Ð½Ð¸Ñ†Ð° Ð”Ñ€. Ð¡Ñ‚Ð°Ð¼ÐµÐ½ Ð“Ñ€Ð¸Ð³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð²

Very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

The code mentioned is working:

1. Create Module1
2. Copy this code:

```vb
Private Declare Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cbMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpDefaultChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long _
    ) As Long

Private Const CP_UTF8 = 65001

Public Function Utf8BytesFromString(strInput As String) As Byte()
    Dim nBytes As Long
    Dim abBuffer() As Byte
    ' Catch empty or null input string
    Utf8BytesFromString = vbNullString
    If Len(strInput) < 1 Then Exit Function
    ' Get length in bytes *including* terminating null
    nBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0&, ByVal StrPtr(strInput), -1, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&)
    ' We don't want the terminating null in our byte array, so ask for `nBytes-1` bytes
    ReDim abBuffer(nBytes - 2)  ' NB ReDim with one less byte than you need
    nBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0&, ByVal StrPtr(strInput), -1, ByVal VarPtr(abBuffer(0)), nBytes - 1, 0&, 0&)
    Utf8BytesFromString = abBuffer
End Function

''' Return length of byte array or zero if uninitialized
Private Function BytesLength(abBytes() As Byte) As Long
    ' Trap error if array is uninitialized
    On Error Resume Next
    BytesLength = UBound(abBytes) - LBound(abBytes) + 1
End Function

''' Return VBA "Unicode" string from byte array encoded in UTF-8
Public Function Utf8BytesToString(abUtf8Array() As Byte) As String
    Dim nBytes As Long
    Dim nChars As Long
    Dim strOut As String
    Utf8BytesToString = ""
    ' Catch uninitialized input array
    nBytes = BytesLength(abUtf8Array)
    If nBytes <= 0 Then Exit Function
    ' Get number of characters in output string
    nChars = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0&, VarPtr(abUtf8Array(0)), nBytes, 0&, 0&)
    ' Dimension output buffer to receive string
    strOut = String(nChars, 0)
    nChars = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0&, VarPtr(abUtf8Array(0)), nBytes, StrPtr(strOut), nChars)
    Utf8BytesToString = Left$(strOut, nChars)
End Function
```

1. Create Module 2.
2. Copy this code:

```vb
Sub Test_Utf8String()
    Dim abData() As Byte
    Dim b() As Byte
    Dim a As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveSheet
        abData = StrConv(.Cells(1, 1).Value, vbFromUnicode)
        a = ""

        For i = 0 To UBound(abData)
            If i = UBound(abData) Then
                a = a & Hex(abData(i))
            Else:
                a = a & Hex(abData(i)) & " "
            End If
        Next

        b = Utf8BytesFromString(a)
        s = Utf8BytesToString(b)
        MsgBox (s)
    End With
End Sub
```

5. After it, copy your proposed test sample
   `"ÐžÐ±Ñ‰Ð¸Ð½ÑÐºÐ° Ð±Ð¾Ð»Ð½Ð¸Ñ†Ð° Ð”Ñ€. Ð¡Ñ‚Ð°Ð¼ÐµÐ½ Ð“Ñ€Ð¸Ð³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð²"`
   on Cell `A1`.
6. You will get [image: this result] according to your plan and [your referral link](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html)

Comment: David, thanks, but it's not really about getting a 'bytes' string. I can get that too actually. I need to display the non-encoded string in cell A1 to something readable, in any language it is originating from... So it might just need some tweaking around in the end. Maybe you can still give it a try?

So many thanks in advance for your effort!

Comment: BTW A completed conditional declaration for 64/32bit Office using `#If VBA7 Then` can be found at [Utf8FromString64](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/basUtf8FromString64.bas.html).

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly the code I found and quoted at the initially provided link:  https://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html. It's this code I need to get working and I couldn't do so yet. Thanks.

Comment: @Demetris - not exactly, it's the exported code module at https://www.di-mgt.com.au/basUtf8FromString64.bas.html and not https://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html

Comment: I just took a look today and it will be difficult if the strings comes in characters from other languages as they will use a different number of "bytes"

Comment: @T.M. Thanks.... I will give it then a last try with that one.

Comment: @David Garcia Bodego Oh well, the code should cater for any language, but if not, I will try what T.M. mentioned and if it doesn't work, I think I have to give it up.